How an Azure Function can call another Azure Function in a different tenant and wait for result?
I have an Azure Function 1 in tenant A that needs to call an Azure Function 2 in tenant B and wait for result from 2. I don't want to make 2 a public HTTP endpoint. In AWS I can set lambda:InvokeFunction iam role on a resource and call the function in the code.
How do I do the same in Azure?

Are you ok with function-level authentication or do you explicitly want Entra ID authentication? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#authorization-keys

I hope that you can do this in 2 ways

Using App Registration
Federated Managed Identity

By using App registartion, you need to provide permission for Tenant B Azure Function to your Tenant A azure function.
Please refer to the below reference for details how to achieve using above 2 methods.
Azure Function accessing resources from another tenant
